How do I delete records from one table that are linked to another table through its PK?
I have a database in a Maui app that has two tables. The first table was setup with a class like this:
public class Groups
{
    [PrimaryKey, AutoIncrement]
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public string? GrpName { get; set; }
}

The other table was created with this class:
public class Sites
{
    [PrimaryKey, AutoIncrement]
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public string? Title { get; set; }
    public string? SiteAddr { get; set; }
    public long GrpId { get; set; }    // The Id number matching the Group Id
    public string? Notes { get; set; }
}

What I'm looking to do is select one or more groups from a datagrid that I already created and delete all Groups and Sites records linked to the Groups table via the GrpId field.
My database file was created like this:
var dbname = GenDbName();  // This generates the database file name.
var dbpath = Path.Combine(dbLoc, dbname);  //This is the full path of the database
var options = new SQLiteConnectionString(dbpath, true);
Conn = new SQLiteAsyncConnection(options);
await Conn.CreateTablesAsync<Groups, Sites>(CreateFlags.AutoIncPK);

I did research in LINQ figuring I could delete the Sites records in a similar way that MySql does it, but I just can't grasp it. Any suggestions?

What db are you using?  Do you want to delete them from the db, or just from the in-memory model?  In SQL, something like delete * from Sites where GrpId = ? should work

I want to delet them from a db. I'm still pretty new to .NET Maui and truthfully I really haven't seen the MySql code like you just showed me. All I've seen is LINQ which I'm still getting more familiar with. What you just showed me in this comment does make sense to me and I am very familiar with it. Would it still work in Maui or would I nee new namespaces?

You should be able to just execute an SQL query against your db.  But I can't be more specific without more info about your db.  Can you post some db access code where you load the data?

This is how the database file was created: 'var dbname = GenDbName(); // This generates a file name.
var dbpath = Path.Combine(dbLoc, dbname);
var options = new SQLiteConnectionString(dbpath, true);
Conn = new SQLiteAsyncConnection(options);
await Conn.CreateTablesAsync<Groups, Sites>(CreateFlags.AutoIncPK);' As I said in my initial question, I posted the classes that form the tables. If you need more info, let me know. Also, when I typed Delete and pressed the space bar in Visual Studios, VS was correcting it to something else. So I couldn't enter the SQL Delete command that you gave me.

@BobGatto that would be helpful info to add into your question. Please consider an edit to your post!

don't stuff code into comments - they're impossible to read

first, you're using SQLite, not MySQL.  That's relevant.  Second, you appear to be using the wrong SQLite library - see the docs for the correct nuget package to use

@BobGatto I second Jason's comment. I believe that the doc references sqlite-net-pcl which would allow you to use the Linq syntax you mentioned if that's something you wish to do.

@IV. the question doesn't contain any LINQ code. LINQ doesn't query or modify databases, it's just a query language that some providers, eg ORMs, convert to SQL

@BobGatto your question doesn't contain any LINQ code. LINQ doesn't query, much less modify, databases. It's ORMs like NHibernate or ORM that convert it to SQL only for querying, to give you the impression of working with objects instead of tables. Any changes made to the objects are persisted by the ORM. You seem to be using SQLite-Net Extensions, in which case you need to use the Delete method to delete objects.

What you ask is called a cascade delete. SQLite will automatically delete related rows if you specify ON DELETE CASCADE when you create a foreign key. Check the Cascade Deletes section in the SQLite-Net Extensions docs. To delete objects, use con.Delete. For cascade deletes, use con.Delete(...,recursive:true). CASCADE DELETE isn't enabled by default and has to be re-enabled on every connection with PRAGMA foreign_keys = ON

BTW since you deal with objects, not tables, you shouldn't use plural names. You have a Group, a site. That single group can contain multiple sites.


var options = new SQLiteConnectionString(dbpath, true); Conn = new
SQLiteAsyncConnection(options);

From the code you shared, we could know that you use nuget sqlite-net-pcl as the local database.
And if you want to delete records from one table that are linked to another table through its PK, you can try to use Nuget SQLiteNetExtensions which is a very simple ORM that provides one-to-one, one-to-many, many-to-one, many-to-many, inverse and text-blobbed relationships between sqlite-net entities.
For your problem, you can try to add a ForeignKey GroupsId for Sites.cs and add CascadeOperation.CascadeDelete attribute for the InnerSites that is related to current group。
Please refer to the following code:
public class Sites
{
    [PrimaryKey, AutoIncrement]
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public string? Title { get; set; }
    public string? SiteAddr { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey(typeof(Groups))]
    public long GroupsId { get; set; }    // The Id number matching the Group Id

    public string? Notes { get; set; }
}


public class Groups
{
    [PrimaryKey, AutoIncrement]
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public string? GrpName { get; set; }


    [OneToMany(CascadeOperations = CascadeOperation.CascadeInsert | CascadeOperation.CascadeDelete)]
    public List<Sites> InnerSites { get; set; } = new List<Sites>();
}

Then if you delete the current Groups from the database, then the relative Sites will be deleted at the same time.
       private SQLiteConnection _connection;

      string dbPath = Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData), "ItemsDb.db");

      _connection = new SQLiteConnection(dbPath);


   public void DeleteItem(Groups item)
   {
       _connection.Delete(item,true);

   }

For more information, you can check: sqlite-net.

The question doesn't contain any LINQ code at all. It seems to that SQLite-Net and SQLite-Net Extension are used.
As the SQLite-Net documentation shows to insert or delete an object you need to call Insert or Delete.
In SQLite itself, and all other databases, related rows will be deleted as well if a foreign key constraint was created with ON DELETE CASCADE, eg :
FOREIGN KEY (customer_id) references customers(id) ON DELETE CASCADE

In other databases this happens automatically. In SQLite though, you need to enable cascade deletes on every connection with :
PRAGMA foreign_keys = ON

To avoid this hassle, SQLite-Net Extensions offers a cascade delete overload that automatically enables the PRAGMA when you pass recurse: true. Extensions also allow you to specify the FK constraints in C# code as object relations :
public class Customer {
    [PrimaryKey, AutoIncrement]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    [OneToMany(CascadeOperations = CascadeOperation.CascadeDelete)]
    public Order[] Orders { get; set; }
}

public class Order
{
    [PrimaryKey, AutoIncrement]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    
    [ForeignKey(typeof(Customer))]
    public int CustomerId { get; set; }
    ...
}

...

var customer = conn.Get<Customer>(1234);

// All orders for this customer will be deleted from the database
conn.Delete(customer, recursive: true);

LINQ is a generic query only language that each provider translates to whatever it needs, eg API calls, URLs or in the case of ORMs like NHibernate, EF or SQLite-Net, SQL. Modifying data is the job of the ORM, not LINQ.
